# Is there a periodic review process to identify users giving too many upvotes or downvotes to some particular user's questions or answers

Tags: discussion, voting

Is there a periodic review process to identify users giving too many upvotes or downvotes to some particular user's questions or answers?

If not, can we have this just to make sure the upvotes and downvotes keep reflecting the quality of the questions and answers?

The reason I ask this question is because I observe a trend that in case of bounty upvotes are more than in case of non-bounty question. For example: Google In-App purchase with multiple account question

- The first question was asked two years back and got only four upvotes (no bounty)
  *[Does In App Billing support multiple accounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263889/does-in-app-billing-support-multiple-accounts)*
- The second question looks like a duplicate, but has a 200 reputation points bounty. 16 upvotes till now
  *[In-app purchases with multiple accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811490/in-app-purchases-with-multiple-accounts)*

Please let me know if I am not correct here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here.  Are you asking whether or not a question with a bounty attached to it gets more upvotes than one that doesn't?

Comment: May be i am completely wrong here... I just observe so thought to ask... Is there moderators or review processes to make sure the up and down are given with good intention

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are there mechanisms in place to detect users who target other users with votes? Yes, and moderators make regular use of these to identify and destroy sock puppet accounts and voting rings. I won't elaborate on the specifics beyond that, but trust me in that we do care about maintaining the voting integrity of the site.

Your point about bounties isn't related to that, though. Because bountied questions are now highly visible via the featured questions tab, they tend to receive a lot of attention and a lot of votes. Whether or not that's a problem depends on who you ask. It's not voting fraud, though.